# How to use delegate like a reference types in c#

Tags: c#, delegates, pass-by-reference

I found that delegates behave like value types, but I want to use them as reference types.

**Is there any way better than just wrap a class over a delegate to make it behave as a reference type?**

First, let me explain what means "behave like a value type":

```
delegate fun void();

void a() { }

void main()
{
    fun A;
    fun B;    
    B = A;
    A += a;
}
```

The result shows that `B` has nothing but `A` has `a`. Here, delegates are like `int` types, such that when:

```
int a = 1;
int B = 0;
int A = 0;

B = A;
A += a;
```

the result is `A == 1` and `B == 0`.

To be more specific, what I want is to let the delegate behave like a pointer, when `A` changes, `B` also changes. When `A += a`, 'B' also gets 'a' implicitly.

Comment: delegate types are immutable, so they don't work as reference types. Also, `A += a` is actually an assignment operation, not a modification of an object. If we think about it in "reference" terms, the `0` is not changed to a `1`, `A` is simply assigned to `1` instead - a whole new object.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. In no case will updating the reference held by `A` also update the reference held by `B`. Perhaps you could post an example with actual reference types that demonstrates the behavior you are seeking?

Comment: Actually, A += a; and then A() calls a() twice. A = a; A +=b; will call both a() and b()

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking if you can update one delegate reference and have it reflected in another delegate reference automatically. You can-- not *exactly* the way you ask, but by chaining the events, you can add a handler to one event and have it called from the other.

For example:

```
delegate void fun();

event fun A;
event fun B;

void main()
{
    A += () => Console.WriteLine("This was added to A");
    B += () => Console.WriteLine("This was added to B");
    B += () => A();  //Chain the events
    A += () => Console.WriteLine("This was added to A after A was already added to B");

    Console.WriteLine("Running B()....");
    B();
}
```

Output:

```
Running B()....
This was added to B
This was added to A
This was added to A after A was already added to B
```

Notice the last line was emitted even though we never added it to `B` directly.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way.

```
delegate void fun();
```

Is a [multicast delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.multicastdelegate) and

```
A += a;
```

is compiled into

```
IL_0035:  call       class [mscorlib]System.Delegate
                     [mscorlib]System.Delegate::Combine
                     ( class [mscorlib]System.Delegate,
                       class [mscorlib]System.Delegate )
```

which returns

```
return NewMulticastDelegate(resultList, resultCount);
```

which returns a new instance of `MulticastDelegate`

[Link to Source Code](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/multicastdelegate.cs)